# Connecting Xbox 360 with TP-Link TL-WA500G access point connected to Linksys WRT54GL wireless router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wrt54g

I'm attempting to connect an Xbox 360 console to a Linksys WRT54GL router (wirelessly), using a TP-Link TL-WA500G wireless access point. I've had this working in the past, but I didn't make a note of the configuration unfortunately. The Internet connection is connected to the router.

The device hasn't been used for several months. During this time, I installed Tomato firmware onto the WRT54GL router, however I have since completely restored the router to factory defaults, by reinstalling the default firmware and performing a hard reset.

Having reset the device, I was surprised to see that the Tomato favicon is still displayed when accessing the router's admin webapp. I can't remember what the default favicon looks like, but I'm guessing it's not a tomato! If anyone could shed some light about this, I'd be grateful.

But more importantly, what am I missing here? I've tried disabling wireless security on both the router and access point. Am I right in using the same SSID on both devices?

If the device can be used to connect an Xbox to the Internet, then presumably it can be used to connect a PC to the Internet. Is this correct, and if so, what mode should the access point be set to? Client? I access point is unable to connect to the Internet when connected to PC in client mode.

The Xbox' network diagnostic tool says: Network Connected, Internet: Not Connected, Xbox LIVE: Not Connected. I've no idea how to troubleshoot this problem further. Any help would be very much appreciated.

The configuration of each device is listed below:

```
Linksys WRT54GL configuration:

Firmware Version:                   4.30.15 build 2, Dec. 8, 2010
Hardware Version:                   1.1
Language:                           English
Internet Connection Type:           Automatic Configuration DHCP
Router Name:                        WRT54GL
MTU:                                Auto
Local IP Address:                   192.168.1.1
Subnet Mask:                        255.255.255.0
DHCP Server:                        Enable
Starting IP Address:                192.168.1.100
Maximum Number of DHCP Users:       50
IP Address Range:                   192.168.1.100 to 49
Client Lease Time:                  0 minutes (0 means one day)
Static DNS 1:                       0.0.0.0
Static DNS 2:                       0.0.0.0
Static DNS 3:                       0.0.0.0
WINS:                               0.0.0.0
Time Zone:                          (GMT) England
Automatically adjust clock for daylight saving changes: Enable
DDNS Service:                       Disable
MAC Address Clone:                  Disable
Operating Mode:                     Gateway
Wireless Network Mode:              Mixed
Wireless Network Name (SSID):       viper
Wireless Channel:                   6 - 2.437 GHz
Security Mode:                      WPA2 Personal
WPA Algorithms:                     TKIP+AES
WPA Shared Key:                     mypsk
Group Key Renewal:                  3600 seconds
Wireless MAC Filter:                Disable
Authentication Type:                Auto
Basic Rate:                         Default
Transmission Rate:                  Auto
CTS Protection Mode:                Disable
Frame Burst:                        Disable
Beacon Interval:                    100  
DTIM Interval:                      1
Fragmentation Threshold:            2346
RTS Threshold:                      2347
AP Isolation:                       Off
SecureEasySetup:                    Enable
Firewall Protection:                Enable
Block Anonymous Internet Requests:  Enable
Filter Multicast:                   Enable
Filter Internet NAT Redirection:    Disable
Filter IDENT (Port 113):            Enable
IPSec Passthrough:                  Enable
PPTP Passthrough:                   Enable
L2TP Passthrough:                   Enable
Internet Access Policy:             Disable
Single Port Forward, Port Range Forward, Port Triggering, DMZ, QoS: Disable
Local Router Access:                mypasswd
Access Server:                      HTTP and HTTPS
Wireless Access Web:                Enable
Remote Management:                  Disable
UPnP:                               Enable
Allow Users to Configure:           Enable
Allow Users to Disable Internet Access: Disable
Log:                                Disable

TP-Link TL-WA500G configuration:

Firmware Version:                   4.2.3 Build 090707 Rel.37067n
Hardware Version:                   WA500G v1 0815311C
LAN Type:                           Static IP
IP Address:                         192.168.1.106
Subnet Mask:                        255.255.255.0
Gateway:                            192.168.1.1 (Linksys WRT54GL router)
SSID:                               viper
Region:                             United Kingdom
Channel:                            6
Mode:                               54Mbps (802.11g)
Operating Mode:                     Client
WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK:                   Enable
Version:                            Auto
Encryption:                         Auto
PSK Passphrase:                     mypsk
Group Key Update Period:            3600 seconds
Wireless MAC Address Filtering:     Disable
Current Connected Wireless Stations numbers: 2
Wireless Statistics:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID  MAC Address     Current Status  Received Packets    Sent Packets
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   TL-WA500G_MAC   WPA2-PSK        265                 79
2   WRT54GL         AP-UP           265                 36
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DHCP Server:                        Disable
Start IP Address:                   192.168.1.100
End IP Address:                     192.168.1.199
Address Lease Time:                 120 minutes
Default Gateway:                    0.0.0.0 (optional)
Default Domain:                     (optional)
Primary DNS:                        0.0.0.0 (optional)
Secondary DNS:                      0.0.0.0 (optional) 
Enable WMM:                         Disable
Enable AP Isolation:                Disable
Disable short preamble:             Disable
RTS Threshold:                      2346
Fragmentation Threshold:            2346
Beacon Interval:                    100
Power:                              Max


Xbox 360 configuration:

IP Address:                         192.168.1.104
Subnet Mask:                        255.255.255.0
Gateway:                            192.168.1.106 (TL-WA500G access point)
DNS 1:                              194.168.4.100
DNS 2:                              194.168.8.100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I managed to get this working and documented how to [connect Xbox 360 to Linksys WRT54GL using TP-Link TL-WA500G with WPA2-PSK security](http://noseyparka.me.uk/2012/04/09/connect-xbox-360-to-linksys-wrt54gl-using-tp-link-tl-wa500g-with-wpa2-psk-security/). This may be of use to others.

Comment: The link is no longer Valid. Here it is from archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20150321230920/http://noseyparka.me.uk/2012/04/09/connect-xbox-360-to-linksys-wrt54gl-using-tp-link-tl-wa500g-with-wpa2-psk-security/

Answer (score 0):

Since this got bumped due to the edit, it shouldn't hurt to add another answer.

The issue might be as simple as making sure that WDS is supported or enabled on the access point and on the bridge device connecting to it. Wi-Fi infrastructure networks cannot be bridged on the client end unless 4-way MAC addresses are used (the access point itself is always a bridge). 4-way MAC address mode is often called WDS. Ad-hoc networks can't be bridged on either end without this feature.